# Windows Server - Redirect Traffic To Another Subnet

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-server-2012-r2, routing, ip-routing

on windows server 2012 I have 2 network cards, one of them connects directly to the router on static ip 192.168.1.11 and that second card I have a second ip set as 192.168.1.12.

From the router I forward the port 22 to 192.168.1.12 which hits the windows server.

On the windows server I then have two Macs plugged into the second network card which has a static ip of 192.168.137.1 and the server hosts 2 linux virtual machines with a bridged connection so they have 192.168.137.2 and 192.168.137.3

What I would like to do if possible is to take the port 22 traffic on 192.168.1.12 and forward it to 192.168.137.2 - but because they're on different subnets then I'm not able to do this directly from the router.

The internet is shared from 192.168.1.11 with 192.168.137.1 so the Mac workstations and VMs have internet access.

Is this possible ? Here is a crude diagram of the setup...

[network diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/92s34.png)

Comment: This "The internet is shared from 192.168.1.11 with 192.168.137.1 .." is not right. IP packet dont get magically "shared". There is a routing oder NATin device (missing in your diagram). Or you do use a /16 subnet, which rendes this question irrelevant.